# File line splitting in Jython

Tags: jython

I am trying to read a file and populate the values in DB with the help of Jython in ODI.
For this, I read the line one by one split the line on the basis of ',' present.

Now I have a line as

```
4JGBB8GB5AA557812,,Miss,Maria,Cruz,,"266 Faller Drive Apt. B",
New Milford,NJ,07646,2015054604,2015054604,20091029,51133,,,
N,LESSEE,"MERCEDES-BENZ USA, LLC",N,N
```

"MERCEDES-BENZ USA, LLC" this field has , within the double quotes due to which it gets split into two fields whereas it should only be considered one. Can someone please tell me how should i avoid this.

```
fields = valueList.split(',')
```

I use this for splitting where valuelist is the individual line present in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `csv` module which can take care of quotes:

```
line = '4JGBB8GB5AA557812,,Miss,Maria,Cruz,,"266 Faller Drive Apt. B",New Milford,NJ,07646,2015054604,2015054604,20091029,51133,,,N,LESSEE,"MERCEDES-BENZ USA, LLC",N,N'

import StringIO
import csv

f = StringIO.StringIO(line)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    print('\n'.join(row))
```

result:

```
...
266 Faller Drive Apt. B
...
LESSEE
MERCEDES-BENZ USA, LLC
...
```

My example uses `StringIO` because test line is as string in code, you can simply use just opened file handler as `f`.

You will find more examples at "Module of the Month": http://pymotw.com/2/csv/index.html#module-csv